# What is R code or function that is equivalent to "Trend Function" in an excel sheet?

Tags: r, shell, command-line, excel-formula, rstudio

I am just wondering what function or R code I can use in R that would be equivalent to 'Trend Function' in a microsoft excel sheet. As trend function in excel is equal to "Returns values along a linear trend. TREND fits a straight line (using the method of least squares) to the arrays known_y's and known_x's. Returns the y-values along that line for the array of new_x's that you specify". I have two column in excel sheet columnY= "absorbances" and columnX = "concentrations"  by using these two columns I need to calculate new_x's that returns the y-value along that line for the array of new_x's that I specify. **My new_x's are unknown absorbances.** What is the easiest way to do this in 'R' as I am spending much time to do it in Excel sheet. I have bunch of (near 300) new_x's values in a excel sheet that needed to be calculate by using columnY and columnX.

Comment: You want to start with `lm`, which fits a linear regression model to your data. Then use `predict` to apply it to new values. But you would need to provide more specific examples of your data in R to get more specific help

Answer (score 1):

`TREND(y, x)` in Excel gives the same result as the following (where `x` and `y` are numeric vectors of the same length):

```
fitted(lm(y ~ x))
```

or to predict different new values (where `x` and `y` are as above and `new_values` is a numeric vector of `x` values for which the `y` values are to be predicted):

```
predict(lm(y ~ x), list(x = new_values))
```

See `?lm`, `?fitted` and `?predict` for more information.

Note that if `x` and `y` each have length 2 then this would also work:

```
approx(x, y, xout = new_values)$y
```